# Retornar o índice do maior elemento de um array

Tags: javascript, array

Eu estou tentando retornar o maior índice do vetor, fiz o seguinte código mas retorna `undefined` na função:

```js
let array = [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 1];
function retornaMaiorIndice(){
    for (let i = 0; i <= array  ; i++){
        var maior = 0;
        let atual = array[i];
        if (array[i] > atual) {
            maior = array[i];
        }
    } 
    return maior;
}

console.log(retornaMaiorIndice(array));
```

Comment: não é `array.length` tem problemas diversos

Comment: Pegar o maior indice ou pegar o maior valor?

Comment: Eu queria pegar o maior índice, a posição digo, tem o vetor por exemplo [0, 1, 2], eu queria que retornasse o índice 2 que seria o maior.

Comment: @Saul44 Se o array for `[10, 20, 30]`, o maior elemento é 30 e o índice do maior elemento é 2. Qual desses resultados vc quer? (no seu exemplo não ficou claro porque os índices são iguais aos valores)

Comment: Como eu disse, indice é uma coisa, valor é outra, pelo seu exemplo você quer o maior valor, indice é outra coisa.

Comment: @hkotsubo eu quero o índice do maior elemento por favor, me desculpem eu formulei mal a minha pergunta.

Comment: @Saul44 os indice deste array `[10, 30, 400]` são 0, 1 e 2 ... os valores são 10, 30, 400, o valor 10 esta no indice 0, o valor 30 esta no indice 1 e o valor 400 no indice 3. Compreende?

Comment: Então o 10 está no índice 0, 30 no 1, e 400 no 2, não seria isso? @GuilhermeNascimento ?

Comment: Isso Saul, então o titulo da pergunta fala pegar o maior indice, mas as respostas lhe retornam o maior valor, ai fica a duvida, vc quer pegar o maior indice (de 0 a 5 no seu exemplo, o resultado seria 5) ou você quer pegar o indice cuja o valor seja o maior (no seu exemplo o indice com maior valor é o indice 4, que tem o valor 10) ou você quer de fato pegar o maior valor (que não tem nada haver com indices)?

Comment: Eu quero pegar o índice, num vetor com 5 elementos por exemplo, retornar o valor 4, posto que vai de 0 a 4.

Comment: @Saul44 eu acho que já entendi, mas essa definição que acabou de dar é bem ambígua ainda.

Comment: Você entendeu minha pergunta, foram 3 situações, o indice se enquadra em duas, duas são sobre pegar indice, o que muda é a condição para pegar o tal indice, então torno a repetir: Você quer pegar o indice com o maior VALOR (no SEU exemplo `[2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 1]` o indice de maior valor é o `4`, pois o valor é `10`)? Ou pegar de fato o "maior" indice (que no seu caso é o ultimo sempre `[2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 1]`, neste caso ESPECIFICO bastaria `let array = [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 1]; let maior = array.length - 1; console.log(maior);`)? Qual das duas?

Comment: O de maior valor no caso o que retorna com array.lenght  - 1, isso mesmo.No caso que você disse seria o valor 4.

Comment: Obrigado, eu me expressei mal, vou me esforçar para na próxima dúvida explicar de uma maneira compreensível.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depois de muitos comentários, o problema era até outro. Como a pergunta teve repercussão eu vou tentar dar uma resposta que seja o que precisa.

Precisa sincronizar o índice que está junto com o maior valor achado em outra variável, porque são dados que precisam ser mantidos e andar juntos.

```js
function retornaIndiceMaiorValor() {
    let maior = array[0];
    let indice = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maior) {
            maior = array[i];
            indice = i;
        }
    }
    return indice;
}

let array = [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 1];
console.log(retornaIndiceMaiorValor(array));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Greatest.js).

Note que dá para achar qual é o índice depois sabendo qual é o maior com `indexOf()`, mais aí eu acho que só valeria a pena se usasse o `max()` para achar o maior.

Para aprender os erros básicos que tinha no código original fica a resposta anterior abaixo. A pergunta beira a ser *off topic* porque estava disante do que precisava de fato, é o tal do [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/101), se é para responder por completo, a dúvida era sobre o `undefined`.

---

O código não faz o menor sentido e tem vários erros.

- A inicialização da variável deve ser fora do laço, caso contrário o maior sempre será 0.
- Você deve encerrar o laço até `i` que chegue no tamanho do *array*, e não se `i`for menor que o*array*, que não é um número, é um objeto complexo com vários dados dentro, então pegue a propriedade certa.
- E deve encerrar antes de chegar no fim porque o índice do *array* começa no zero, ele não pode pegar o índice que seja igual ao tamanho porque esse índice não existe, é como ter 10 dígitos, vai do 0 ao 9, não existe o 10.
- Aí compara se `array[i]`  é maior que `array[i]`, o que obviamente não é já que é igual, não tem como ser diferente, talvez a criação da variável desnecessária tenha confundido. Curiosamente escrevendo certo dá para ler fácil porque tem que comprar com `maior` mesmo.
- Usei o 0 para ficar na regra original, mas se permitir valores negativos aí teria que pegar o menor valor negativo possível ou começar pegando um elemento inicial para comparar. Esse código funciona para esses números, não como regra geral.
- Mudei o nome da função para indicar com clareza o que ela faz, se queria retornar o índice do maior valor então o nome deveria ser `retornaIndiceMaiorValor()` e aí a lógica seria diferente porque teria que controlar qual é o índice do maior valor também.
- O resto eu melhorei pra simplificar e organizar.

```js
function retornaMaiorValor() {
    var maior = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if (array[i] > maior) maior = array[i];
    return maior;
}

let array = [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 1];
console.log(retornaMaiorValor(array));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Greather.js).

Considerei que este é um caso que a pessoa está aprendendo fazer isso assim, é um exercício de codificação, e como tem vários problemas no código seria importante mostrar como fazer o mesmo código, mas corretamente. Em códigos em produção um código mais simples e mais pronto é mais interessante, o Augusto demonstrou essa forma.

Comment: Mais um negativo sem sentido dado por quem só quer tumultuar. Note que eu não reclamo de negativo que dá para ver que pode ter algo, que foi de um usuário que pode não ter gostado de algo pontualmente, mas sempre dado por pessoa que quer mostrar que vai me punir toda vez que ela fica desagrada com alguma coisa que nada tem a ver com a resposta é duro de engolir. Na verdade a minha até aponta todos os erros, mesmo os menores.

Comment: Esse código é muito bom!! E ao invés de 0 é possível colocar um outro valor que o javascript permite! Que é o Infinity, só que ao invés de colocar somente Infinity, coloque o valor maior como -Infinity. Então, assim qualquer valor dentro do vetor será maior que -Infinity, e portanto o primeiro elemento do vetor, mesmo que seja negativo já será considerado como o maior elemento do vetor!

Comment: @LeonardoOliveira na verdade o infinito só poderia ser usado, e até seria o caso de usar mesmo se quisesse achar o menor.

Comment: sim sim, eu sei! Mas como no caso ele quer encontrar o maior, então o Infinity não pode ser usado.

Comment: Se é uma negativação continuada tem ser punida. Vote porque discorda ou vote porque concorda com conteúdo, mas não vote por problemas pessoais,

Comment: @AugustoVasques sim, é mais ou menos assim, claro a pessoa não sai negativando sem parar, ela sabe lidar com o limite do sistema, mas eu não posso fazer nada pra não parecer que a perseguição é minha. Note que é uma pessoa diferente da de ontem :D Os 2 hoje disputam pra ver que é o maior negativador em cima de mim, e eles não negativam tanto assim outras pessoas (um deles até negativou outros 2 abastante, mas não tem feito mais), o sistema não olha essas nuances. Não olha que depois de uma treta a pessoa mudou o padrão de voto e passou de positivador pra negativar quase 100%.

Comment: @Maniero eu acabei de dar um voto positivo, eu estou aprendendo, ontem quando fiz esse código nem cheguei a analisar direito por cansaço, muito obrigado por responder minha pergunta, muito bem detalhada a resposta mas poderia me indicar como eu retornaria o maior índice quando digo isso falo da posição no array, exemplo: [0, 1, 2] eu queria o valor 2, porque o vetor começa em 0 como você disse.Muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: @Saul44 Note que as pessoas votaram para fechar sua pergunta por ela não estar clara. Eu inicialmente achei que estava clara, mas cada vez mais parece que não está. Quando vai resolver um problema a primeira coia que precisa fazer é saber todos os detalhes necessários e usar os termos corretos principalmente para falar com outras pessoas. Se não consegue fazer isso, precisa aprender antes, porque isso vai fazer falta a vida inteira. Valor e índice são coisas diferentes, até agora não está claro qual dos dois deseja,

Comment: mesmo no comentário agora não dá para saber qual dos dois deseja, porque o valor e o índice são iguais nesse exemplo. Então sem uma pergunta muito clara fica difícil dar uma resposta certa. E não sei se adianta muito arrumar agora por causa das respostas já dadas em cima do que deu para entender, e já bem positivadas.

Comment: @Maniero a posição do valor do vetor, no caso a maior, [20, 30, 40], respectivamente 20 ocupa 0, 30 ocupa 1, e 40 ocupa 2, eu queria retornar a maior posição neste caso 2, me expressei de maneira correta agora?

Comment: Agora sim, nesse exemplo, você conseguiu se explicar. Você deseja o índice do maior elemento na lista. Diversas implementações de buscas em arrays retornam -1 para indicar que não foi possível encontrar o elemento em questão (isso só daria em caso de lista vazia, mas tem outros usos em buscas gerais, como procurar pelo elemento `100` dentro de `[20, 30, 40]`)

Comment: @Saul44 Parece que você quer mesmo o índice, mas ainda não está totalmente claro, porque está em ordem crescente e poderia ser coincidência, eu ach oque entendi, mas tinha achado antes e errei. Se você disser que entre `[10, 40, 20, 30]` quer que o resultado seja 1, portando o índice de onde está o maior valor da lista, aí já parece ficar mais claro. Isto até estava dito na pergunta, mas o código indicava outra coisa. Porém, tem certeza que quer isso? Costuma fazer pouco sentido precisar dessa informação.

Answer (score 14):

Para encontrar o maior valor dentro de um vetor você pode usar o método [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) que retorna o maior de um ou mais números:

```js
var lista = [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 1];
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, lista));
```

Também possível fazer o mesmo código usando a [sintaxe de espalhamento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) que permite que um objeto iterável seja expandido para ser usado onde zero ou mais argumentos são esperados:

```js
var lista = [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 1];
console.log(Math.max(...lista));
```

Comment: E se a lista for vazia, a resposta é o quê?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ai faz um if antes de executar :P (é uma sugestão): `console.log(lista.length ? Math.max.apply(null, lista) : 0);` ou `if (lista.length) { return Math.max.apply(null, lista); } else { return 0; }` se for pra retornar em uma função e tiver algo a mais para aplicar

Comment: Ambos, questionamento e resposta, são uteis e interessantes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, foi mais uma curiosidade. Não estou acostumado com JS, mas em outros cantos que oferecem coisa similar, tem um valor padrão de retorno ou mesmo algo como um mônado para indicar que "não teve retorno" (como o `IntStream.max` do Java)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, perfeito! Tem que ser perguntado mesmo. Como Maneiro colocou na resposta dele é um código de produção e pessoa tem que sair daqui sabendo quais os obstáculos.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado mas esta correto em questionar, em JS retorna -Infinity se eu não me engano, o que provavelmente não é o esperado, pelo código do AP retorna "zero", então ajustei o primeiro comentário com a sugestão. Eu pessoalmente acho que não precisamos resolver tudo no "minimalismo", o Augusto eu sei que entende bem de lógica da programação, mas vejo muitos usuarios aqui no site perguntando que nem sabem usar IF, ELSE, ||, && e quando eles se deparam com coisas simples eles pensam que tudo pode se evitar "lógica"

Comment: Augusto, editei o primeiro comentário com a sugestão. Apesar de eu ter ainda sim questionado o  AP: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436409/retornar-o-maior-elemento-de-um-array#comment843839_436409

Comment: Sim: https://ideone.com/0GhUdi tem que fazer uma guarda, ou antes se é vazio e nem tentar ou depois se voltar isso

Comment: Sua resposta mostra uma forma melhor de obter o maior, mas será que isso ajuda a tirar as dúvidas da pergunta? Talvez quem fez a pergunta fique sem saber o que está errado e apenas copie o código e cole para resolver uma situação ;)

Comment: @RicardoPontual, perfeito. Entendi e acato a orientação.

Answer (score 9):

Seu código tem vários problemas:

- no `for` para saber o tamanho do array precisa usar `array.length`:
- é preciso iniciar a variável maior apenas antes de começar o `for`;
- é preciso ver se o valor atual é maior que a variável `maior` e não `atual`.

Veja como ficou com essas correções:

```js
let array = [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 1];
function retornaMaiorIndice() {
    var maior = array[0]
    // iniciando o for com o elemento da posicao 1, pois o maior já é, temporariamente, o da posicao 0
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] > maior) {
            maior = array[i];
        }
    } 
    return maior;
}

console.log(retornaMaiorIndice());
```